# Reverse a list in python with a condition

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to sort this list in this way:

.log suffix should be the first item

and .gz file should be in a descending order

```
my_list = [
     '/abc/a.log.1.gz',
     '/abc/a.log',
     '/abc/a.log.30.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.2.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.5.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.3.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.6.gz',
     '/abc/a.log.4.gz',
]
```

expected_result:

```
my_list = ['/abc/a.log',
        '/abc/a.log.30.gz',
        '/abc/a.log.6.gz',
        '/abc/a.log.5.gz',
        '/abc/a.log.4.gz',
        '/abc/a.log.3.gz',
        '/abc/a.log.2.gz'
        '/abc/a.log.1.gz']
```

`reversed(mylist)` is also not getting me the desired solution.

Comment: You need to sort with own comparator

Comment: please explain @MarcinOrlowski

Comment: You need to have a method /function that would decide thr right order by any logic you want. This is called comparator and implementation differes depending on version yet https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html is a good start as it covers that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like you are trying to sort file names. I would recommend using `os.path` to manipulate these strings.

First you can use `os.path.splitext` split out the extension to compare between `.log` or `.gz`. Then strip off the extension again to get the file number, and convert it to an integer.

For example:

```
import os

def get_sort_keys(filepath):
    split_file_path = os.path.splitext(filepath)
    sort_key = (split_file_path[1], *os.path.splitext(split_file_path[0]))
    return (sort_key[0], sort_key[1], int(sort_key[2].strip(".")) if sort_key[2] else 0)

print(sorted(my_list, key=get_sort_keys, reverse=
```

I am relying on the fact that the `log` extension will sort after `gz` lexicographically.

Answer (score 3):

I would use this sort helper:

```
import re
def sort_helper(i:str):
    m = re.search('^.*?(\d+)(\.gz)',i)
    try:
        return int(m.group(1))
    except AttributeError:
        return 0

print(sorted(my_list, key= sort_helper, reverse=True))
```

Perhaps using a re is overkill, but it is a flexible tool.
To get around the lack of a leading zero in your filenames, return an int.

also, note the use of the lazy operator at the start of the regular expression:

```
^.*?
```

not just

```
^.*
```

this matches a little as possible, letting the match for the numbers in the filename be as greedy as possible.